# How to get slick slider working well on multi-directional(RTL/LTR) site?

Tags: 8

After install [slick slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick) and [Slick Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_views) modules on multi-directional site, Slider does not work well on RTL, There is option in slick slider module for RTL sites, but this broke slider on LTR, So we need this an option enabled only on RTL sites, I found this solution. How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by implementing template_preprocess_slick

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;

/**
* preprocess variables for slick.html.twig templates.
*/
function template_preprocess_slick(&$variables) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
  if($language->getDirection() == 'rtl') {

    $settings = $variables['content_attributes']->offsetGet('data-slick');
    if(!empty($settings)) {
      $settings = Json::decode($settings->value());
      $settings['rtl'] = true;
      $settings = Json::encode($settings);
      $variables['content_attributes']->setAttribute('data-slick', $settings);
    }
  }
}
```